# Этимология слова "скаляр"

Tags: этимология

Слово *скаляр* и производное прилагательное *скалярный* (напр., скалярная величина) произошли от латинского *scalaris* "ступенчатый". А как так получилось, что величина, характеризуемая только числовым значением, связана со *ступенчатостью*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**СКАЛЯР** (от лат. **scalaris ― ступенчатый**) (скалярная величина) ― величина, каждое значение которой (в отличие от вектора) может быть выражено одним (действительным) числом, вследствие чего совокупность значений скаляра можно изобразить **на линейной шкале** (скале ― отсюда название). Длина, площадь, время, температура и т. д. ― скалярные величины.

[Скаляр | enc-dic.com](http://enc-dic.com/word/s/Skaljar-38081.html)

**Шкала ― от лат. scala** ― лестница, производное от scandere ― подниматься. Итак, родственными являются слова **скаляр, шкала, а также эскалатор**.